# MockBackend I am confused

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, backend, testbed

So i try to test my component methods which include services. I will show you an example of what i have done in order to test my search method.

This is my component containing the search function:

```
  search(idntDocTp:any,idntDocNo:any){

this.providersService.searchForSupportingStaffList(idntDocTp,idntDocNo).subscribe(
      data => {
      this.searchSupportingStaffData = data[0];
      if (this.searchSupportingStaffData != null)
      {
        this.activeIndex = 1;

        switch (this.searchSupportingStaffData.IdntType) {
          case 'nID':
           this.identificDocNumSymbol = 'NID';
            break;
          case 'passport':
            this.identificDocNumSymbol = 'PAS';
            break;
          case 'arc':
          this.identificDocNumSymbol = 'ARC';
            break;
        }
      } else {
        this.alertMessage = { severity: 'warn', summary: 'Warning Message', detail: 'No records were found. Please try again.' };
        this.alertMessagesSrv.pushAlert(this.alertMessage);
      }
});
```

This is my service

```
searchForSupportingStaffList(idntDocTp:any,idntDocNo:any): Observable<any> {

    let costructUrl: string;
    costructUrl = this.searchSupporting_staffUrl + '/?IdntType=' + idntDocTp + '&IdntNo=' + idntDocNo;
    return this.http
    .get(costructUrl, 
                { headers: this.headers }
            )
    .map((res: any) => res.json().data);
}
```

This is the test i am doing in order to check if my service works (declarations):

```
beforeEach(() =>  {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    ProviderManagementModule,
    // HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
],
//declarations: [ SupportingStaffComponent ],
providers: [
    AlertMessagesService,
    ProvidersService,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory:(backend,options) => new Http(backend,options),
      deps:[MockBackend,BaseRequestOptions]
    }
]})
//Get the MockBackend
backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);
//Returns a service with the MockBackend so we can test with dummy responses
service = TestBed.get(ProvidersService);

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SupportingStaffComponent);
app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;});
```

And here is the actual test

```
 it('return Search results and active index is changed',  fakeAsync(() => {
    let response = {
      data: [
        {id:1, name:'DummyName', IdntType:'nID', IdntNo:'991212', age:'27', start_date:'12 Sep 2017', end_date:'',contact_number:'99457845'}
    ]
  }


    backend.connections.subscribe(conn => {
          conn.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: JSON.stringify(response) })));
        });
        service.searchForSupportingStaffList('dummyData','dummyData');
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
       expect(fixture.componentInstance.activeIndex).toEqual(1);
       expect(fixture.componentInstance.searchSupportingStaffData.name).toMatch('DummyName')
       expect(app.data.length).toBe(1);
      }));
```

The test runs successfully. It doesnt matter what parameters i set to the service function it still return the mock data. That is why i am confused. I thought that i provide the service with mock data and if i search with wrong parameters the service will not return anything, But this is not the case. Can someone explain me if i am doing smth wrong? In addition even if execute the search method from my component rather the service still getting the same results. How i actually understand if the test is ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine since you hard coded the response and I think you are not doing anything wrong here. Testing the service is testing the external api of the service not the return data.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. But how I test if my method does what is supposed to do? For example here I want to test if my method actual works an search for data based on parameters

Comment: You are welcome sir. Testing the data based on the parameters means that you would be testing the backend api or contract which is out of the scope of a unit test.